For what topological space, every point in an open set $S$ in this topological space has a closed neighborhood inside $S$?
Under this question, the comment says the following

It is not true that every point in an open set $S$ in a topological space has a closed neighborhood inside $S$.

I am not sure why and is there an example? Also, for what kind of space $X$, we can say that every point in an open set $S$ in $X$ has a closed neighborhood inside $S$? For instance, what about $X = \mathbb{C}$ the complex space?

Spaces with that property are called regular spaces. All metric spaces are regular. The space $X={0,1}$ with open sets $X$, $\varnothing$, and ${1}$ is not regular; this is the so-called Sierpiński space.

The property you are referring to is "regular". At π-Base, Search for ~Regular you can see at least 78 spaces that fail to satisfy that property.
One example is the cofinite topology on an infinite set. In this space, closed sets are finite, or the entire space. This means that the only closed neighborhood of a point is the entire space, which is not contained within any proper subset of the space.
